# iOS Safari font-kerning/letter-spacing issue for Avenir

Tags: ios, css, fonts, safari

There is a weird behaviour in iOS Safari where a specific font-weight of 900 for Avenir font produces an extra space on the right of characters `fi`.

[image: Weird space after fi]
[image]

I tried using 'Avenir Heavy' which corresponds to that font-weight but the issue is is still apparent. It does not appear on any other font-weights though, just on that 900 weight. I tried playing around `-webkit-font-kerning`, `-webkit-font-smoothing`, `letter-spacing`, but none solves the issue.

Is there a CSS-only way of working around this? Or is this an issue on the font/browser itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same issue, but with font weight 400 on iOS Safari. I was able to identify a workaround that hopefully generalizes to others with the same situation. By adding the following CSS :

```
text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
```

This disables kerning and ligatures, and likely the spacing irregularity after "fi" is a kerning issue (potentially specific to the font file, but that is beyond my knowledge).